# Object variable not set error in lotusscript

Tags: lotusscript

I'm trying to get input from user and replace the user entered value in particular field. I have tired the below code but i'm getting an "Object variable not set error". Not sure about where i'm missing. Please help to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

```
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim item As NotesItem
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    rfield = Inputbox("enter name")
    If rfield = "" Then 
        Exit Sub
    End If
    nval = Inputbox("Enter the purpose ")
    Call doc.ReplaceItemValue( Cstr(rfield), "Name")
    Call doc.ReplaceItemValue(Cstr(nval),"Purpose")
    Call doc.Save(False,True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Tip: next time, use the LotusScript debugger first! See Tools/Debug LotusScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not initialised the `doc` variable.  You can set it like this:

`set doc = ws.currentdocument.document`

As an aside, you should also read up on error trapping.  This will help you find out which line is causing issues.